# How Do I Call a Constructor from a Class to Another One in a Different Class?

Tags: java, class, oop, constructor

I'm just learning OOP in Java. I'm trying to call a constructor from another one to enter a message. Thank you for your help. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Sample {
    private String User;
    private int ID;

    public Sample(String user) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        User = user;
        ID = 0;
        User = sc.nextLine();
        ID = sc.nextInt();
    }//CONSTRUCTOR

}//Sample

public class Sample_2 {
    private Sample user1, user2, user3;

    public Sample_2() {
        user1 = new Sample();   //FROM HERE I WANT TO CALL THE OTHER CONSTRUCTOR ABOVE.
        user2 = new Sample();
        user3 = new Sample();
    }//CONSTRUCTOR

    public static void main(String args[]){

    }//main

}//Sample_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no default constructor (i.e. with no arguments) for `Sample` so you need either to add one, like this:

```
class Sample{

    private String User;
    private int ID;

    public Sample() {
        /* something */
    }

    public Sample(String user){
        // ...
```

**or** to use the one with a `String` parameter, like this:

```
public Sample_2(){
   user1 = new Sample("some string"); 
   // ...
```

For some reading, see this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) on constructors